# Expand only one row in the table

Tags: html, angular

I have a table with rows, where I list the data from json file.
In one row I'm slicing the data to show only 100 symbols.
I want to display full text when user click on the row. I managed to do it, but It opens all rows. How to do it only for the one row, which clicked?

```
<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist | filter:searchText">
    <td (click)="fullViewFlag= !fullViewFlag" class="text-left">
        <span *ngIf="fullViewFlag">{{lfiexport.desc}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="!fullViewFlag">{{lfiexport.desc | slice:0:100}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, did the answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same `fullViewFlag` multiple times, so it will effect all the rows. So, I suggest you maintain different `fullViewFlag` properties for each object and can try the below code

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqznpy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**TS file**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  lfilist = [{
    desc: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  }, {
    desc: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
  }, {
    desc: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
  }].map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      fullViewFlag: false
    }
  });
}
```

**Template file**

```
<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist">
  <td (click)="lfiexport.fullViewFlag = !lfiexport.fullViewFlag" class="text-left">
    <span>{{lfiexport.fullViewFlag ? lfiexport.desc : lfiexport.desc | slice:0:2}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

No need of `*ngIf` we can use terinary operator `?:`

Comment: Sivakumar, hello! Sorry, I didnt have time to test it till today. Its working perfectly! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @АндрейЦюрин Glad to hear that it helped you ;) can you upvote too?